# How can i change the color of placeholder in SearchBar in Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchbar

I have this design of the search bar and the output is not the same.

[image: All i get is the normal grey background of this object]

I have tried TintColor, BackgroundColor, Different Styles in addition to many extensions on the internet and yet i still cannot achieve it.

All what i have so far is the normal searchbar with the grey area color at the placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the textColor for placeholder in SearchBar you need to extract the `searchField` from `searchBar` and then `placeholderLabel` from `searchField`. Here's how:

```
let searchField = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
searchField?.textColor = myColor

let placeholderLabel = searchField?.value(forKey: "placeholderLabel") as? UILabel
placeholderLabel?.textColor = myColor
```

Comment: And how to set the forKey values in storyboard. ?!

Comment: You have to do it programmatically by giving an `@IBOutlet` for `serachBar`.

Comment: I think i did not reach what i wanted, i do not want to change the placeholder color, What i want is to change the default background of the text to White, when its oiginally has a graybackground, followed by a white background for the Searchbar.